# React component remounting on another component props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react-router-redux application that has a voip calls handling bar on top of all pages. The voip bar has a timer that counts time for a call with an interval that increments the time every second.

For some reason, every time the voip bar re-RENDERS cause of a prop change, the shown page (using react router) gets re-MOUNTED. I have no idea why since the voip bar isn't even a child/parent of the page.

I really don't know why this happens. I thought that perhaps the route changes on every prop change hence causing a remount, but it isn't the problem.

The layout:

```
<div className={classes.layout} id='layout'>
  <Header isAuthenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated} username={this.props.username} />
  <VoipBar />
  <main className={classes.content} id='page-wrap'>
    {this.props.children}
  </main>
  {/* <Footer /> */}
</div>
```

As you can see the VoipBar is not a parent of the pages (pages are the children inside the main tag).

The interval that gets called is an interval that dispatches an action every second. The action's reducer is this:

```
case actionTypes.UPDATE_PHONE_TIMER:
  return {
    ...state,
    seconds: state.seconds + 1,
    time: formatTime(state.seconds + 1)
  }
```

And I am using 'time' in the VoipBar component this way:

```
<div className={classes.twilioLog} style={{color: this.props.logColor}}>{`${this.props.twilioLog}${this.props.time ? `: ${this.props.time}` : '' }`}</div>
```

**To sum up**, The timer on the voipbar should update each second according to the call time, and it should not affect the page at all. Right now every time the voipbar updates, the whole page re-mounts.

EDIT: I found out that if I remove the HOC I wrap my pages with, the page no longer re-renders. For some reason right now the HOC re-renders on every voipbar prop change. The HOC is there for authentication (purely front end). I still don't understand what's happening there though. This is my HOC:

```
import React from 'react';  
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
import * as actions from '../../store/actions';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {  
  class Authenticate extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      if (!this.props.username || !this.props.role || !this.props.siteAccess) this.props.logout();
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      username: state.auth.username,
      role: state.auth.role,
      siteAccess: state.auth.siteAccess
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      logout: () => dispatch(actions.logout())
    };
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Authenticate);
};
```

The relevant route:
`<Route path='/profile/person/:personId' component={withAuth(PersonProfile)} />`

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

React's documentation says:

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

`shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

Comment: I am familiar with shouldComponentUpdate, but if you'll read again you'll see that my problem is that the component gets re-mounted and not re-rendered :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue with react-router.
The mistake I made was to use the `component` prop instead of the `render` prop while using the `Route` from react-router.

According to their documentation, the `component` prop re mounts the entire route when anything in the router changes. However, the `render` prop calculates the diff and **re-renders** the diff

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried what you said and while it didn't help, it DID help me focus on my problem. editted :)

Comment: Hey. I think the problem is that everytime you call the `withAuth` function, it returns a newly created class. React views this as a change and renders the whole thing again, which causes a new `ComposedComponent` to be created everytime.

There are better ways of implementing auth. Please check: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: Also, you may still want to move from `component` to `render` in your `Route`. Else, you'll still face the issue.

Comment: I tried changing to render but it didn't work.. I didn't pass it right I guess. I tried doing this: `<Route path='/profile/person/:personId' render={props => withAuth(PersonProfile)({...props})} />` but it isn't right.

Comment: You may have to move away from the wrapper function you have created, withAuth.
That is bound to cause a re-mount everytime.

Comment: Im not locked on that idea. I'll look at the link you provided :)

Comment: I did as the guide says, the remounting is still happening.. :(